# Does detecting particle or delayed choice affect quantum tunneling?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-tunneling

As much I have read quantum tunneling is propagation of wave function through barrier, and it is possible because of wave nature of particles. Now my question is will particle tunnel if it is detected before and after tunneling(as in modified double slit or delayed choice), because detection will collapse wave (potential) function so if particle is detected before tunneling it will not tunnel and if detected after tunneling it should not have tunneled at first place.

Comment: The particle can be detected before or after tunnleing, but once it is detected it can never be observed again.

Comment: How so. Is there any paper on ot.